# updating data in database using datagridview C#

Tags: c#, database, insert, updates

I have a problem with my code regarding editing data in database using a `DataGridView`.

I have an error at `da.update(dt);` It says,

> *Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against
>   a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information.*

When i change the `SELECT` to `UPDATE/INSERT` I get an error at `da.fill(dt);`.

What is wrong with my code?

Here's my code:

```
private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) > {
    con.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM RegistrationTable", con);
    da.Fill(dt);
    dt.Rows[dgvREGtable.CurrentRow.Index].BeginEdit();
    dt.Rows[dgvREGtable.CurrentRow.Index][0] = tbFirstname.Text;
    dt.Rows[dgvREGtable.CurrentRow.Index][1] = tbLastname.Text;
    dt.Rows[dgvREGtable.CurrentRow.Index][2] = tbEmail.Text;
    dt.Rows[dgvREGtable.CurrentRow.Index][3] = tbContacts.Text;
    dt.Rows[dgvREGtable.CurrentRow.Index][4] = tbUsername.Text;
    dt.Rows[dgvREGtable.CurrentRow.Index][5] = tbPassword.Text;
    dt.Rows[dgvREGtable.CurrentRow.Index].EndEdit();
    SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
    da.Update(dt);
    displayrecords();
    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your select query needs to return the primary key of the table.  If your table doesn't have a primary key, you need to set one.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the easiest way to achieve this is to actually bind the DataGridView to your dataset, then the bindings will handle all the ugly stuff for you. For example:

```
DataSet mydata = new DataSet();
// populate your dataset however you like
DataBindingSource mybindingsource = new DataBindingSource(typeof(DataSet));
mybindingsource.DataSource = mydata;
DataGridView mydatagridview = new DataGridView();
mydatagridview.DataSource = mybindingsource;
```

Thats the nitty gritty way, but its much easier in designer to achieve this.